# How to recognize real scenes image using scikit-learn?

Tags: python, image, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am new in scikit-learn, I have a lot of images and images size not all same, A kind of are real scenes image like 
cdn.mayike.com/emotion/img/attached/1/image/dt/20170920/12/20170920121356_795.png
cdn.mayike.com/emotion/img/attached/1/image/mainImg/20170916/15/20170916153205_512.png
, 
another are not real scenes image like
cdn.mayike.com/emotion/img/attached/1/image/dt/20170917/01/20170917011403_856.jpeg
cdn.mayike.com/emotion/img/attached/1/image/dt/20170917/14/20170917145613_197.png
.

I want to use scikit-learn recognizing which not real scenes image, I think it simlar to http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_face_recognition.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-applications-plot-face-recognition-py. 
I am totally no idea how to begin.
How to creating dateset and extracting features from images? 
Can someone tell me what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to not directly be a programming problem here and your questions are related to non-basic 'current' research.

It seems that you should read about *Natural Scene (Statistics)* and get yourself familiar with one of the current machine learning frameworks like [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/), [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/).

There are many tutorials out there to get started, for example you could begin with a binary classifier which outputs if the given image shows a natural scene or not.

Your database setup could have a structure like so:

```
-> Dataset
    -> natural_scenes
    -> artificial_images
```

[Digits](https://developer.nvidia.com/digits) for example can use such a structure to create a dataset and is able to use models designed for [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/) and [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/).

I would also recommend that you read about finetuning nerual networks, as you would need a lot of images in your database if you start training from scratch.

In Caffe you can finetune pretrained models like CaffeNet or GoogeNet.

I think those are some basic information which should get you started.

As of scikit-learn and face-detection: Face-Detection is more looking for local *candidates* or image patches which could possibly contain a face. Your problem on the other hand is more of a global problem as the whole image is concerned. That said I would start off with a neural network here which is able to extract local and global features for you.